# How to make this php function more efficient

Tags: php, math

Basically i am trying to do a simple 5 star rating system, using font awesome classes for the stars.

Full star

```
<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
```

No star

```
<i class="fa fa-star-0"></i>
```

Half star

```
<i class="fa fa-star-half-0"></i>
```

So i loop through each review for my service like seen below:

```
$i=0;
$reviewRating = 0;

foreach($service['reviews'] as $review){
   $i++;
   $reviewRating += $review['rating'];
}
```

From this i now have the amount of reviews and the total of all review ratings added together.

I pass both of these values into my function as seen below:

```
function get_rating_stars($reviewRating,$i){
    //rounding number to nearest .5
    $rating = round($reviewRating/$i * 2) / 2;
    $cnt = 0;
    $class = "";//class active gives the star a colour, if empty it shows as a empty star.
    $zeros = false;//this is for when we have gone past the .5 meaning any further stars have to be a zero(empty star).
    $starList ="";//This will be returned when built up

    while($cnt < 5){//because there will always be 5 stars showing, regardless to full half or empty
        if($zeros){
            $starList.= '<li><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>';
            $cnt++;
        }else{
            if($rating == 0.5){
                $starList.= '<li class="active"><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i></li>';
                $zeros = true;//now we have output the half star all following will be empty
                $cnt++;
            }else{
                //the first loop will normally start here unless rating starts at 0.5
                if($rating > 0.5){$class = "active";}else{$class = "";}
                $starList.= '<li class="'. $class  .'"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>';
                $cnt++;
                $rating--;
            }
        }
    }
    return $starList;
}
```

So this function i made does do the trick and works exactly how i want it too, however that it has to repeat this process for every single service on the page. So when i loop through all services i loop through each review and do this, it just seems a bit over kill.

This function could theoretically get called 20 times , as i can show up to 20 services on one page.

Does anyone know how i can make this more efficient?

Comment: Is it actually slow? Or are you just guessing (hint - dont guess, profile)

Comment: well its not exactly majorly slow. But it just seems like overkill from looking at it, and a lot of other php functions will be created here at a later stage so i'm trying to make each function as efficient as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure about improving your current implementation, but how about this: Use the average rating to create CSS classes like `fa-star-3` (3.0) and `fa-star-4_5` (4.5) and then change the way to render your ratings. ;)

Comment: @MHakvoort [Stack Exchange is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/269301)

Comment: *"[Ceci n'est pas une pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images)."*

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this function (from yours). Although if it works then yours should be fine.

I have no idea if mine is faster than yours either so it's merely an alternative.
(Plus I think mine is a little easier to read, but that's just preference)

```
function get_rating_stars($reviewRating,$i){
    // Calculate Rating
    $rating         = max(0, min(5, round($reviewRating/$i * 2) / 2));
    $halfStar       = (int)$rating != $rating;
    $arrayResult    = array_fill(0, $rating, '<li class="active"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>'); // Full Stars
    if($halfStar){
        $arrayResult[] = '<li class="active"><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i></li>'; // One half Star
    }
    $arrayResult    = array_pad($arrayResult, 5, '<li><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>');  // Empty Start
    return implode('', $arrayResult);
}
```

Comment: where does the $seperatorHTML come into the function?